# Linux sequence function isn't working properly in a bash script

Tags: bash, seq

I'm working on a Linux course and during a scripting lesson, the instructor uses a ping-sweeping function as an example. It is meant to iterate through potential IPs on a network from 1 through 255 and return the ones that reply. The code is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in 'seq 1 254'; do
ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" &
done
```

This is within a file called ipsweep.sh, which we then call with

```
./ipsweep.sh [first three tuples of IP]
```

When I run the script, I get the result

```
ping: [myIP].seq: Name or service not known
```

So what I assume is it's not reading seq as a function and simply hitting it and trying to throw it into my script as is. Obviously an IP like 192.168.1.seq doesn't exist so we run into this.

I don't fully understand the syntax of the sequence function because I'm new to Linux and scripting in general, but I've tried using

```
for ip in (seq 1 254); do
```

instead but the script won't recognize the parenthesis. Essentially I just need to know how to get the 'seq 1 254' function to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `seq` is not part of bash itself, nor is it POSIX-standardized to provide a solid guarantee that it will exist or have any particular behavior for an OS or distro to be able to call itself POSIX-compliant. Consider using the shell's built-in syntax instead: `for ((ip=1; ip<=254; ip++)); do`

Comment: But more importantly, `“` (the character your code uses) is not `"` (the ASCII double-quote character, which is the only one shell syntax recognizes). Voting close-as-typo.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sounds like the smart quotes were some bizarre copy & paste error, not in the actual script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a command and return its output, use `$()`:

```sh
for ip in $(seq 1 254); do
    # Note ASCII double quotes
    ping -c 1 "$1.$ip" | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" &
done
wait # Wait for all the background processes started in the loop to exit.
```

Or given you're using `bash,` use [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) instead of running an external program:

```sh
for ip in {1..254}; do
    # ...
done
```

Comment: So I guess when I copied and pasted from my VM it changed the quotes used because my code has the proper quotes included. Does waiting just prevent any errors from occurring while the loop is ending?

Comment: @rugbyralph288 It pauses the script until all those background pipelines finish.

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn mentioned, $() is usually the preferred way to expand commands. But grave accents (or "backticks" as they're sometimes called) *can* also be used. The issue your code ran into is that it uses the wrong type of accent - acutes (´) instead of graves (`)